# Product files not deleting after WIX upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, wix, wix3.10

We use a managed bootstrapper.

We have two products in our bundle (let's call it `BundleName`) - `ProductA` and `ProductB`.
We install both products and it works fine.

Next we change a version of `BundleName` from `1.0.0.0` to `2.0.0.0` and the MSI version of `ProductA` from `1.0.0.0` to `2.0.0.0`.

Performing upgrade. It completes successfully but in the log of `BundleName 1.0.0.0` (previous version of bundle that should be uninstalled) we have:

```
Will not uninstall package: ProductA, found dependents: 1
Found dependent: {ffe63ad2-5155-4958-91cc-b0aac330cdb6}, name: BundleName
Will not uninstall package: ProductB, found dependents: 1
Found dependent: {ffe63ad2-5155-4958-91cc-b0aac330cdb6}, name: BundleName
```

Nevertheless, it works fine.

The problem appears when we remove the upgraded `2.0.0.0 BundleName`. The bundle removes it successfully and logs are clear, **but it does not remove any files and registry keys of `ProductA`.**

One more thing we noticed in `2.0.0.0` logs  also a bit strange:

`Planned package: ProductA, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: **MinorUpgrade**, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register`

We changed the first number of version, so it should be `MajorUpgrade` not `MinorUpgrade`.

Here is our configuration:

```
<Product
   Id="$(var.ProductCode)"
   UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"
   Name="$(var.ProductName)"
   Language="1033"
   Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
   Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)">

<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)" />
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of $(var.ProductName) is already installed." 
              Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
              AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />
...
```

Could somebody please explain what we missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
`ProductCode` in `Product` element was fixed, not `*`.

[How To: Implement a Major Upgrade In Your Installer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html)

[How To: Generate a GUID](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/generate_guids.html)